# Access different LocalStorage from PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following issue. I have several work centers with different access tokens, which I store separately in localstorage:

```
      var nombretoken = "tokencentro"+idcentro;
      localStorage.setItem(nombretoken, result.value);
```

Now I need to make a call to a file that makes a connection with an API by sending the token stored in the local storage, and I have the problem that I don't know how to go from the local storage to the php of the file. I think that to process it in the file, instead of doing an include I have to pass it to a method and call it (In order to pass the parameters) (Unless there is a way to call localstorage from the PHP file itself) what I don't know is how to load the corresponding token (As you can see, each work center has its own, and a user who uses this can have several work centers) and that it is stored separately in the localstorage. Thanks.

```
include "importar_data.php";
```

Comment: You need to make an ajax request?

Comment: I don't have the problem with an ajax request, the problem is that if the user has 3 different work centers... How do I send the 3 tokens through the ajax)

Comment: So show us how you are storing those 3 different work centers in localstorage. You can send post request to your PHP file with multiple params.

Comment: You mean there are 3 different tokens stored in the localstorage? Well, get all 3 of them and you can send them all in one ajax request if you like. Why is that a problem?

Comment: It is a problem because my knowledge of Ajax and Javascript is small and I don't know how to make a loop in Ajax and Javascript that makes the different tokens of the centers go in the Ajax call

Comment: Just put them all in one object, and that will send them as 3 parameters to the request.

Comment: This post shows two ways to do that  (there are others too): https://medium.com/meta-box/how-to-send-get-and-post-requests-with-javascript-fetch-api-d0685b7ee6ed

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, I have solved it like this. First of all, in the form I have made a cycle where I have created an input for each work center and assigned the corresponding value:

´´´

```
<?php 
$consulta_centros= $Centro->listarCentros();
     if($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_centros)){
         do{
             $idcenter = $lista['id'];
             $nombretoken = "tokencentro".$idcenter ;
             ?>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $nombretoken ?>" id="<?php echo $nombretoken ?>">
                 <script>
                       var idta = "<?php echo $idcenter ?>";
                       var nombretoken = "tokencentro"+idta;
                       var tokencentro = localStorage.getItem(nombretoken);
                       $("input[name='"+nombretoken+"']").val(tokencentro);
                 </script>
             <?php
         }while($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_centros));
     }
```

´´´

And then before the file call I collected the received value:

```
$nombretoken = "tokencentro".$idt;
$token = $_POST[$nombretoken];
```